# Will this code create consistent storage of data in my contract? + How to use memory properly

Tags: ethereum, solidity, web3js

I am writing a simple contract as a "backend" for a website of sample social media posts. From a frontend website using web3, I will let users add posts, and then when the webpage is loaded, I will ideally want to read all these posts saved in the contract (and display on the website). Everything (`RegularPosts`) should be stored persistently.

This is my sample code, am I on the right track? Very new to Solidity -

```
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

contract Storage {

    struct RegularPost {
        uint256 category;
        string name; 
        string post;
        address addr;
        uint256 date;
    }
    
    RegularPost[] public RegularPostArray;

    function addNewPost(uint256 _category, string memory _name, string memory _post, uint256 _date) public {
        RegularPostArray.push(RegularPost({category: _category, name: _name, post: _post, addr: msg.sender, date: _date}));
    }    

    function getRegularPosts() public view returns (RegularPost[] memory) {
        return RegularPostArray;
    }
        
}
```

So a few questions:

- Will this persistently store an array of posts as pushed to?
- What is the storage limit on something like this?
- Am I using the `memory` keyword properly/as needed? Do I need to use the `storage` keyword?
- When `getRegularPosts()` is called (via e.g. web3), what exactly will be returned? Will I (can I) get a JSON of everything? I'm not sure what I will receive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Will this persistently store an array of posts as pushed to?*

Yes. The contract doesn't have any code that would rewrite or delete the items, and the storage is persistent.

---

> *What is the storage limit on something like this?*

A dynamic-size storage array can have up to `2^256` items, which is the limit of the index datatype (`uint256`).

The actual storage slot location within the EVM storage is calculated using a hash of the index and few other params (see the [docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.9/internals/layout_in_storage.html#mappings-and-dynamic-arrays)), so there is a theoretical possibility of hash collisions, but it hasn't been proven in practice.

---

> *Am I using the `memory` keyword properly/as needed? Do I need to use the `storage` keyword?*

I'm assuming you mean the `RegularPost[] memory` as part of the `getRegularPosts()` return statement (and not the `string memory` in the `addNewPost()` function params).

This is a correct use, because the `return` statement can only use `memory` or `calldata` location. So the script loads the `RegularPostArray` from storage to memory, and then returns it from the memory.

An example use of the `storage` location is inside a function, when you're pointing to a storage variable:

```
function updatePost(uint256 _postIndex, uint256 _newCategory) external {
    // any changes to the `post`
    // will be stored in the `RegularPostArray[_postIndex]`
    RegularPost storage post = RegularPostArray[_postIndex];
    post.category = _newCategory;
}
```

But if you use a `memory` location, Solidity works with the in-memory copy of the variable and doesn't update the storage:

```
function notUpdatePost(uint256 _postIndex, uint256 _newCategory) external {
    // any changes to `post`
    // will NOT affect `RegularPostArray[_postIndex]`
    RegularPost memory post = RegularPostArray[_postIndex];
    post.category = _newCategory;
}
```

---

> *When getRegularPosts() is called (via e.g. web3), what exactly will be returned? Will I (can I) get a JSON of everything? I'm not sure what I will receive.*

It depends on the web3 library implementation (e.g. JavaScript library can return the data in a different structure compared to Python) and its version. But to be specific, in case of `web3js@1.4.0`, it's an array of arrays, where each of the inner arrays represents the struct (with the values duplicated as both number-indexed and assoc-indexed):

```
[
  [
    '1',
    'a',
    'a',
    '0x86beB187A30265Ce437C0BB55f38aF21554659Ae',
    '1',
    category: '1',
    name: 'a',
    post: 'a',
    addr: '0x86beB187A30265Ce437C0BB55f38aF21554659Ae',
    date: '1'
  ],
  [
    '2',
    'b',
    'b',
    '0x86beB187A30265Ce437C0BB55f38aF21554659Ae',
    '2',
    category: '2',
    name: 'b',
    post: 'b',
    addr: '0x86beB187A30265Ce437C0BB55f38aF21554659Ae',
    date: '2'
  ]
]
```